# Flash Builder 4.4, Application crashes every time when i start profiling and take memory snapshort?

Tags: crash, profiling, flash-builder

i have a real wired problem, when ever i start profiling my application in Adobe Flash builder and take a memory  snapshot the application crash, and these dialogs appears.

[image]

i have tried Adobe **flash builder 4.4, 4.5, 4.6** all of these have same behavior on **window xp**, while on **mac os x** the **4.6** version is working fine for profiling but the debug mode crashes every time. while **4.4 and 4.5** crashes on profiling and working fine for the rest of the work.

[image]

help required

regards.

Comment: I really think that you'll have more luck with this question in the Adobe forums, or better yet, directly contact the Adobe support.

Comment: i have tried this before posting this question here http://forums.adobe.com/message/4553325#4553325 but still no ans :(

Comment: Seems like the Adobe support is your best option then. The problem is definitely not generic, my colleagues and I haven't experienced such issues with FB4.6 on OS X Lion. Maybe delete all FB files including your workspace and reinstall it.